# Gibbs Sampling in R and C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have checked gibbs sampling in different programming languages; in R

```
  x <- rgamma(1,3,y*y+4)
  y <- rnorm(1,1/(x+1),1/sqrt(2*(x+1)))
```

in c++

```
  x = R::rgamma(3.0,1.0/(y*y+4));
  y = R::rnorm(1.0/(x+1),1.0/sqrt(2*x+2));
```

If it uses R functions why it differs in c++ as rgamma takes no n=number of observation and it takes scale instead of rate as default input and rnorm has no n= number of observation as well.

For Rcpp it is totaly different such as;

```
 y = ::Rf_rnorm(1.0/(x+1),1.0/sqrt(2*x+2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's  your question?

`R::rgamma()` is from Rcpp too.  It conveniently wraps the C-level, non-namespaced `::Rf_rnorm()`.

Note that you also have the *vectorised* `Rcpp::rnorm()` -- and that there are plenty of Gibbs Sampler examples out there following the initial post by Darren Wilkinson.  Our best example may be [this page at the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gibbs-sampler/).

*Edit:* And as you are evidently confused over the `shape = 1/rate` parameterization, here is a complete and worked example for you:

We compile a convenience R function calling C++ via Rcpp first:

```
R> cppFunction("NumericVector callrgamma(int n, double shape, double scale) { 
+                  return(rgamma(n, shape, scale)); }")
R>
```

We then call R, making sure we fix the seed:

```
R> set.seed(42); rgamma(3, 2.0, 2.0)   # calling R
[1] 1.824478 0.444055 0.779610
R>
```

Now, using *the same seed*, we call the C++ function *and we make sure we respect the "1/over" reparameterization* as well:

```
R> set.seed(42); callrgamma(3, 2.0, 1/2.0)   # calling Rcpp
[1] 1.824478 0.444055 0.779610
R>
```

Comment: What I'm asking is if you put rgamma function like in Rcpp (rgamma(3.0,1.0/(y*y+4));) it is totally different than R's usual one how does the R get you just ask for 1 number of observation indeed it is not mentioned and how it takes 1.0/(y*y+4) instead of (y*y+4)?

Comment: That is a known issue due to the fact that the _C interface offered by R_ is different from the _R interface offered by R_.  Check the header file `Rmath.h` and see the _Writing R Extensions_ manual.

Comment: I see. How can I code     
    rgamma(length(N_sparse),shape=N_sparse,scale=1/(lambda[ij[,1]]+lambda[ij[,2]]))

in Rcpp?

Comment: See above, and next time _please_ see all the posted examples as eg on my blog, on the Rcpp Gallery and other places.