# Rcpp Armadillo randg()

Tags: g++, rcpp, armadillo

I couldn't run my Rcpp Armadillo code

```
return arma::randg<arma::mat>(n,1,arma::distr_param(shape,scale));
```

It returns error;
Error: randg(): C++11 compiler required

my g++ version is 5.1.0. What should I do?

Comment: You could consider reading the Rcpp documentation on how to turn on C++11 compilation.  We explain it clearly.  Also, search engines can be helpful---works for me in the first hit.  Have you really not yet come across the Rcpp manuals or the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) ?

Comment: I have checked many sites related with this issue but it seems there is no problem related with g++ version but I still have this problem.

Comment: @Shin - add `-std=c++11` to your compiler flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) has a tags, and under the tag `c++11` you will find [three dedicated answers to C++11 and Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/c++11/).

The first of these has this example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int useAuto() {
    auto val = 42;      // val will be of type int
    return val;
}
```

It has everything you need, including *explanation of the plugin adding the required `-std=c++11` switch to your compiler invocation*.

Note: I already told you in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988602/gibbs-sampling-in-r-and-c) to look at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Note 2: And when you search here at StackOverflow in the search box above with a string such as `[rcpp] c++11` you also get 124 results.

Comment: I read all answers that you mentioned but maybe I miss some points. 

c='
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int useAuto() {
    auto val = 42;      // val will be of type int
    return val;
}
'

cppFunction(code=c)

I still have  unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11' problem

Comment: As I told you before,  read the Rcpp Attributes vignette.  It explains this.

Comment: I have solved the problem I added '// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]' at the beginning of the code and it is solved.

Comment: Yes, of course. The post explaining that has been in the Rcpp Gallery since January 2013.

Comment: yes and it is marked as correct answer. Also there might be System->Advanced System Settings ->Enviromental Variables -> PATH problem to be taken into consideration about these problems.

Comment: No, we generally do not care for solutions that work on only one operating system.  Hence the plugin (or, back in the day, setting the env.var programmatically as shown there).