# Generate Random Gamma in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have vector shape and scale parameters to generate numbers from random gamma distribution. I couldn't find a way in R like;

```
lambda<-matrix(rgamma(p,ak,scale=1/bk),p,1)
```

So I'm trying to generate in a loop and it seems I lose time which is the main purpose to use Rcpp.

```
for(int i = 0; i<p;i++){
lambda(i)=arma::conv_to<double>::from(arma::randg<arma::mat (1,1,arma::distr_param(ak(i),pow(bk(i),-1))));
}
```

edit: I have simulated all 3 methods and compare time.

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat rg(const arma::mat& w,double scale,int num) {
int p = w.n_rows;
arma::mat lambda(num,p,arma::fill::zeros);  


for (int j=0;j<num;j++){
for(int i = 0; i<p;i++){
    lambda(j,i)=arma::conv_to<double>::from(arma::randg<arma::mat>(1,1,arma::distr_param(w(i),scale)));
}
}
return mean(lambda.rows(0,num-1),0);    
}
```

These are R codes;

```
fun<-function(w,sca,num){
p=nrow(w)
lambda=matrix(0,num,p)
for (jj in 1:num){
    for (i in 1:p){
        lambda[jj,i]=rgamma(1,w[i],scale=sca)
    }
}
return(colMeans(lambda))
}

fun2<-function(w,sca,num){
p=nrow(w)
lambda=matrix(0,num,p)
for (jj in 1:num){      
        lambda[jj,]=rgamma(p,w,scale=sca)       
}
return(colMeans(lambda))
}
```

Here is result;

```
  a=matrix(c(1,2,3))


  microbenchmark(rg(a,2,100000),fun(a,2,1e5),fun2(a,2,1e5))
  Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    rg(a, 2, 1e+05)  891.6197  900.0092  952.3833  915.6609  991.7918 1271.9117   100
    fun(a, 2, 1e+05) 1018.6645 1059.3994 1171.9160 1130.7481 1200.3192 1754.3445   100
   fun2(a, 2, 1e+05)  321.8309  339.2670  373.5317  355.5914  395.1515  604.4365   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand that `arma::randg` is from the Armadillo namespace?

Whereas `R::rgamma` (scalar) or `Rcpp::rgamma` (vectorised) are from R / Rcpp with the parameterization of `rate = 1/scale` -- which I explained to you in [this earlier question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988602/gibbs-sampling-in-r-and-c)?

**Edit:** This is basically the same answer [as the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988650/143305): a simple C++ call to the *C++ versions of `rgamma`* compared to the *R* version using the "1/over" parameterization.

```
R> set.seed(42); stem(rgamma(100, 0.5, 2.0)) # calling from R

  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the left of the |

   0 | 00000000000001111111112222222333345566677777778888990111111122345666
   2 | 002257268
   4 | 235788
   6 | 269457
   8 | 70345
  10 | 28
  12 | 1
  14 | 
  16 | 0

R> cppFunction("NumericVector callrgamma(int n, double shape, double scale) { 
+                                        return(rgamma(n, shape, scale)); }")
R> set.seed(42); stem(callrgamma(100, 0.5, 1.0/2.0))  # calling from C++ 

  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the left of the |

   0 | 00000000000001111111112222222333345566677777778888990111111122345666
   2 | 002257268
   4 | 235788
   6 | 269457
   8 | 70345
  10 | 28
  12 | 1
  14 | 
  16 | 0

R>
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question sir. I say I have a column scale matrix lets say 5x1. I want to generate 5 random number from gamma dist. (number of observation is 5) by using that column matrix like in R without any loop.

Comment: _Au contraire_ --  I showed you just that in [the previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33988650/143305) because `Rcpp::rgamma()` _is_ in fact  vectorized, just as I mentioned in the answer here. See how what I named `callgamma()` calls `Rcpp:rgamma()` with first argument 3?  Guess what happens when you make that 5?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question if I changed scale arg. type to NumericVector, it doesnot work.

Comment: See the first line of my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help but my question is neither about scale-rate complication nor about vector output. My question is about vector input(arg) for function. As I tried in my code the idea is to use p dim scale, rate or shape arg as an input to our random gamma generator function.

Comment: What makes you believe functions `rgamm` or `randg` for _vector-valued scale, rate or shape_ exist?

Comment: rgamma in R has this property like  rgamma(5,1,seq(1:5)) generate 5 different outcomes but I couldn't find a way in Rcpp?

Comment: You seem to assume that everything that exists in R has to exist in C++.

Comment: I was about to make a comment here trying to explain to you how open source works (hint: you could write a patch / pull request) but there is probably no hope in that making any sense in the context of this and other questions. So I'll just let it rest.

Comment: It seems that the request is simply to allow for using, say, a vector with the random number generator function in Rcpp. For example, when using rnorm in R, we can provide a vector for both the mean and the scale. This would be quite useful in Rcpp.